# Specify width (flex) of Sidebar component

Tags: material-ui, admin-on-rest

I am using admin-on-rest in another app. Here I use the Sidebar component for my toolbar. However, Sidebar does **not** have an overwrite style property.

How can I inject my custom styles into the Sidebar component and more specificaly how can I change the width which is currently defined like this:
https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/src/mui/layout/Sidebar.js#L19 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used the standard mui theme to handle this. See this issue for reference: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/pull/651